# rpy2: unable to import R package

Tags: python, r, rpy2

Here is the R package that I want to use via python:

`> library(abodOutlier)
Loading required package: cluster`

Trying to import this within python using r2py:

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr

base = importr('base')
utils = importr('utils')
cl = importr('abodOutlier')

ImportError: cannot import name 'abodOutlier'
```

But, if I try to import the cluster package, it works. Can someone please tell me what is wrong with my code? This is is my first time using r2py.

Answer (score 0):

The R package "cluster" is normally installed with R ("recommended" package) while the package "abodOutlier" might be installed elsewhere (check the R documentation about "R_LIBS", for example).

I suspect that here your R knows that it should look for additional installed packages in a directory while when running Python/rpy2 that information is missing.